# Deleted Fedora partition, can't boot into Ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I have installed Windows 7, Windows 10 TP, Fedora and Ubuntu in my computer. I have logged into Windows 7 and deleted the Fedora partition and since then I can't boot into any OS. I am struck at grub rescue window and `ls` lists few partitions but all of then do not contain `/boot/grub`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your Fedora partition contained the information related to GRUB.

Nothing to worry, just reinstall GRUB using some method.
For reinstalling it using Ubuntu live CD, follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/11932).

For more details check [How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).